# In a progressively enhanced site how do you avoid retrieving data or rendering the page twice when using a react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

When developing a progressively enhanced app, the website is first developed server side rendering only and then JavaScript is used to enhance the experience. This means that with JavaScript disabled the website should still be fully functional and render correctly.

I am new to react and the challenge I am currently facing is that for the react application to take over the site and manage the route, it will run all components including the retrieval of data which is then added to the state. This means that even when the website is fully rendered and functional react will start from scratch and re render the page on which the user has entered the site. Anything from then one will be handled by the SPA, i.e. react and react-router.

Apart from the unnecessary network requests, this causes the ui to flash until it rerenders. How could I avoid this? On bespoke SPAs I would populate the JavaScript state while rendering the server-side (if the user has JavaScript). The SPA would then handle any routes.

Note that the server-side is not developed using react yet.

Comment: So a UI written purely in JavaScript should still run the exact same when JavaScript is disabled?

Comment: Check out the react docs about server rendering. Redux also has documentation on server rendering. Using the methods from the documentation React does not need to "start from scratch" and will piggy back on what is rendered from the server.

Comment: Correct @Marc C.  The JavaScript used to render the server side is run on the server and therefore is always available and doesn't need the browser to have JavaScript enabled.

Comment: @realseanp understood, but is it possible without rewriting the backend to use React or is that a requirement? (assume we are converting an existent application to an SPA)

Comment: In order to get the full benefits of server side rendering with react you would need to use the react server rendering methods. Otherwise you could add some kind of loader that hides after react renders to the DOM. You could use a noscript tag and write a stylesheet that hides to loader if the user doesnt have JS

Comment: Using a loader will still cause a rerender, it will just be hidden from the user behind the loader. I understand that the *only* option would be using react on the server-side too?

Comment: You are correct.